# Understanding the prime ideals in the ring of dual numbers over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> I want to understand $\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2))$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $R:=k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ is the [ring of dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number).

Here is my attempt:

Every element in $R$ can be written as $a+b\epsilon$ for $a,b\in k.$ If $a\neq 0, \ a+b\epsilon$ is invertible and $(a+b\epsilon)(a^{-1}+ba^{-2}\epsilon)=1.$ Now from the following result in commutative algebra

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$ and $m\subset R$ is an ideal such that every element in $R-m$ is a unit. Then $R$ is a local ring and $m$ is its maximal ideal.

we conclude that $R=k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ is a local ring and the principal ideal $(\epsilon)$ is the maximal ideal. We know that the prime ideals in the quotient ring $R$ are in $1:1$ correspondence with the prime ideals in $k[\epsilon]$ that contain $(\epsilon^2)$. What is $\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon])$? Well the primes in $k[\epsilon]$ are $(0)$ and $(\epsilon-a)$ for all $a\in k.$ Since  $(0)$ does not contain $(\epsilon^2)$, the only possibility is that primes in $k[\epsilon^2]/(\epsilon^2)$ could be of the form $(\epsilon -a) + (\epsilon^2)$ for $a\in k.$ Does a general $a \in k$ work here? No: we know from above that $R$ is a local ring with $(\epsilon)$ being its maximal ideal. Hence every prime ideal must be contained in this unique maximal ideal $(\epsilon)$. So this means that if $(\epsilon -a) + (\epsilon^2)$ for $a\in k$ is a prime ideal in $R$, then we must have that

$$
(\epsilon) \supset (\epsilon -a).
$$

However if $a\neq 0,$ then above containment is not true. Hence we conclude that 
$$
\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)) = \{(\epsilon)\}. 
$$

Is my answer and reasoning correct?

Comment: $(\epsilon^2)$ which in fact is the zero ideal, is not prime since the quotient is not integral. In fact, the only prime is $(\epsilon)$.

Comment: Point noted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, there is a quicker argument which doesn't use the fact that the ring is local, nor the Nullstellensatz and so doesn't require that $k$ is algebraically closed : as you said, primes of $k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ are in bijection with primes $\mathfrak{p}$ of $k[\epsilon]$ which contains $(\epsilon^2)$. Now $k[\epsilon]$ is principal so $\mathfrak{p}=(p)$ and $(\epsilon^2)\subset(p)\Leftrightarrow p|\epsilon^2$. Now the only irreducible polynomial which divides $\epsilon^2$ is $\epsilon$.

Comment: Beautiful argument. Is there a way to find the primes when $k$ is a general ring, or is this too much to ask for?

Comment: I think this is too much to ask for because there is no characterization of primes in $R[x]$ for a general ring $R$, is this correct?

Comment: If $\mathfrak{p}\subset R[\epsilon]$ is a prime containing $\epsilon^2$, it must contains $\epsilon$. Now let $\mathfrak{p}'=\mathfrak{p}\cap R$ which is a prime ideal of $R$. If $x\in\mathfrak{p}$ then $x=a+b\epsilon$. But then $b\epsilon\in\mathfrak{p}$ so $a\in\mathfrak{p}'$. In the end, $\mathfrak{p}$ is of the form $\mathfrak{p}'[\epsilon]+(\epsilon)$ for a prime $\mathfrak{p}'$ of $R$.

Comment: @ Roland Is this a smooth affine variety?