# Definition of ring of dual numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In an exercise from Vakil's algebraic geometry notes, he asks us to describe the set $\rm Spec\space k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$, where $k$ is a field. A comment from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855818/understanding-the-prime-ideals-in-the-ring-of-dual-numbers-over-a-field) question gives a solution, but it's under the assumption that $\epsilon$ is transcendental, and so the assumption may be made that $k[\epsilon]$ is a PID. However, I am not sure why we can assume this. In the question, Vakil says "you should think of $\epsilon$ as a very small number, so small that its square is 0 (although itself is not zero)". If $\epsilon$ is any number we want, they we can certainly choose a value for which $k[\epsilon]$ is not a PID. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is $\epsilon$ if not a free variable? That's what would settle the question.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is not a "number" and Vakil isn't assuming anything; that notation means "take the quotient of the polynomial ring on a formal symbol $\epsilon$ by the ideal generated by $\epsilon^2$" by definition. He is trying to give some intuition for how the resulting ring behaves.

Comment: So what notation signifies that $\epsilon$ is a formal symbol and not a specific "small number" as Vakil says?

Comment: @ponchan: that's just what $k[\epsilon]$ means. Vakil's use of "you should think of" indicates that the rest of the sentence is trying to give an intuition rather than making a rigorous statement. $\epsilon$ can't be an actual element of the field $k$ because no nonzero such element squares to zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The precise definition is $k[\epsilon]=k[X]/(X^{2})$, where $\epsilon = X \bmod X^2$. Then $\epsilon^2=0$.

$k[\epsilon]$ is a PIR because it's a homomorphic image of $k[X]$, but it's not a domain because $\epsilon$ is a zero divisor.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number